# How to add a view as a filter criteria to an other

Tags: 7, views

I've got a View of nodes with a taxonomy term as an exposed filter (category of the node). Thus, the search result is a list of nodes of a specific category. In addition, I've got a second View (in a block) that currently displays all the the nodes of the same Content Type.

What I want to achieve here is (when I use my first view to browse a category) to display the node results of the first view to the second view (instead of displaying all the nodes).

Is it possible to add a view as a filter criteria on an other view?

I would appreciate some ideas =)

Comment: if you want to display node results of the first view then what is the problem in using only the first view ? Can u please explain a bit more regarding what do you wnat to achieve ? .Its just so that I could understand your goal a bit better..

Comment: you can do it easily, Replace the block in search result. Which means hide the 2nd view block in search result path and show the new block in search result only(design the new block similar like 2nd view).

Comment: @user13198 I'm not sure if I can do this just by using one view. My two views got different "Format". My first view is just there as a search box or smth, in a block, while my second view (again on a block) is always displaying node results almost on every page.

Comment: so do you want a view which will display all the nodes belonging to a particular category ? Am I right ?

Comment: no matters, just add new display for Block and then make a same format

Comment: @Bala What if I want to have two different displays at the same time? Like a listing of nodes plus a Grid display on the same view results? Yep I want a view which will display all the nodes belonging to a particular category that has been selected from an exposed filter.

Comment: So is it possible to have two displays printed for the same view? How?

Comment: Yes it is possible to set two display, Under Displays just click add and choose block and save it. then go to admin/structure/block, arrange the new block  to the particular region and set visible only to the search result path

Comment: the new display of the view I've created is quite independent though. Is not reducing the results depending on the filter criteria the other display of this View has.

Comment: for that you need to click the override button and then customize it

Comment: @Bala could u elaborate more on this?

Comment: see the screenshot. Once you added the new block, you have to click on the fields you need to override. http://i43.tinypic.com/2myyz6d.jpg . If you not understand  google how to override block in D7.